# ORA-01858: because of date issue iin insert and merge

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column with DATA type date and another table also with datatype date.

I am using an insert statement to insert into tab1 like :

```
insert into tab1 
(Select date_from,col1,col2

from tab2,tab3
where tab2.date_from =tab3.date_from
and tab2.val='DES');
```

now this is throwing

```
SQL Error: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
*Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
           incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
           required by the format model.
*Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
           elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.
```

When using something like :

```
merge
INTO    hr.TAB1 trg
using   (
       select * from( select distinct T1.rowid as RID, T2.CODE1, T2.SOURCE_SYSTEM_OWNER, T2.DATE_fROM  ,
       ROW_NUMBER() over (partition BY NAME order by t2.CODE1) rn
        from    HR.TAB1 T1
        join  XX_ORG T2
        on      UPPER(T1.NAME) = UPPER(T2.NAME)
        where   uppeR(T1.name) = upper(T2.NAME))
        where  rn=1
    --    and t1.ORGANIZATION_NAME='TMI Operations, M1'
        ) src
ON      (trg.rowid = src.rid)
when matched then update
    set TRG.CODE1 = SRC.CODE1,
   trg.DATE_fROM=  =SRC.DATE_fROM;
```

Gtting

```
    Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
30926. 00000 -  "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"
*Cause:    A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml
           activity or a non-deterministic where clause.
```

Comment: What type is `tab2.val`?

Comment: Can you please post the structure of your tables, or at least the type of relevant fields on the three tables?

Comment: You should list the target columns explicitly: `insert into tab1 (date_col, col1, col2) select ... ` (and the parentheses around the select are useless)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name- I have updated my post. I am facing the same issue in merge statement

Comment: I'm not seeing what your two different errors have to do with each other. The ORA-30926 is caused by duplicates in the `using` clause, so try it on its own and find out why that's happening - presumably `upper(name)` is not unique in one or both of the tables being joined on it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the parentheses?

```
insert into tab1 
Select tab3.date_from,col1,col2
from tab2
join tab3 on tab2.date_from =tab3.date_from
where tab2.val='DES'
```

**Edit**:

You may need to specify inserted columns. Something like

```
insert into tab1 (c1, c2, c3)
Select ...
```

Comment: also add an alias for `date_from`?

Comment: Or use the table name.
Without knowing the data types there is not much to help.

Comment: Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression

Getting this error

Comment: Done. Missed that detail.